# Showing that a space is not complete

Tags: metric-spaces, normed-spaces

Consider the following question:

Let $c>1$ be a real number, and let $F_c$ be the space of sequences $\mathbf{a}=\left(a_1, a_2, \ldots\right)$ of real numbers $a_i$ with $\sum_{r=1}^{\infty} c^{-r}\left|a_r\right|$ convergent. Show that $\|\mathbf{a}\|_c=\sum_{r=1}^{\infty} c^{-r}\left|a_r\right|$ defines a norm on $F_c$.

Let $F$ denote the space of sequences a with $\left|a_i\right|$ bounded; show that $F \subset F_c$. If $c^{\prime}>c$, show that the norms on $F$ given by restricting to $F$ the norms $\|\cdot\|_c$ on $F_c$ and $\|\cdot\|_{c^{\prime}}$ on $F_{c^{\prime}}$ are not Lipschitz equivalent.

By considering sequences of the form $\mathbf{a}^{(n)}=\left(a, a^2, \ldots, a^n, 0,0, \ldots\right)$ in $F$, for $a$ an appropriate real number, or otherwise, show that $F$ (equipped with the norm $\|\cdot\|_c$ ) is not complete.

---

I did the first part but I am struggling with the second and third parts.

For the second I know that the two metrics are equivalent if the identity is continuous, that is a set is open in if and only if it is open in the other. For Lipstich we require that the identity map is further Lisptich. I am struggling to understand how to construct a counter example to this property.

For the third part the obvious candidate seems to be $a=c$, however, the sequence that is generated is obviously not Cauchy, so we can't proceed with that. Everything with less than $c$ automatically doesn't work because of the comparison test. Greater than $c$ I seem to get the same issues as with $a=c$.

Could someone help me understand the approach to the last two parts of the question?

Comment: To establish non-Lipschitz equivalence of two norms on a vector space $X$, you should show either that $\|\mathbf x\|_1/\|\mathbf x\|_2$ can be arbitrarily large, or that it can be arbitrarily small. There's a pretty simple sequence of elements of $F$ that will do the job here! For the third part, can you spell out what you mean by "Everything with less than $c$ automatically doesn't work because of the comparison test."? (hint...). Remember you're showing $F$ is incomplete, not $F_c$, and that this mean you have to find a sequence *of sequences* with no convergent subsequence.

Comment: Hi, thanks for the comment. I think I was able to do the second part; I let $a= c- \epsilon$ and with some estimates I showed that the fraction can be arbitrary large as we wish.  For the last part my issue is that I need to give a sequence of their desired form. Moreover, I could be misunderstanding but isn't completeness a notion to do with cauchy seuqneces and not about subsequences?

Comment: You're right about Cauchy sequences/subsequences - I got a bit ahead of myself there! You may know that compactness and completeness are quite closely related, but indeed we should be showing incompleteness here. In the third part, it's telling you to look at a sequence of elements of $F$ that looks like $(a, 0, ...), (a, a^2, 0, ...), (a, a^2, a^3, ...), ...$. This sequence will "want to" tend to $(a, a^2, a^3, a^4, ...)$, but this doesn't lie in $F$! If you pick an $a$ so that it does lie in $F_c$, then it's fairly easy to see it's a Cauchy sequence with no limit in $F$. Does this help?